# cannot extract APK in IONIC

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

I have created a  mobile application. Angularjs ionic and editor is vscode. then i tried to get apk from the code. sdk was installed  externally without android studio. API level that i instaalled in sdk is api level 23(marshmillow).

when i tried to get apk using "ionic cordova build android --release" the output says"

failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

How to solve the Problm.?[image: This is the output of ionic info.]

here is the Android Home varriable and path vaariables.[image: Android Home][image: PATH]

How to solve this error.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add JAVA_HOME in environment variable.

[image]

Comment: @Dinuka Darshana Thanks for verifying my answer. please do upvote too.